# inheriting from multiple classes?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have the following hierarchy of interfaces and implementations in Java:

```
A <- B <- C

A_impl <- B_impl <- C_impl
```

where `A <- B` means `B` extends `A`, and `A_impl` implements `A`, etc.

Now I want to extends `B` with `D`, while extending `C` and `D` with `E`, in other words:

```
A <- B <- C <-|
     <- D <-- E
```

I have `D_impl` extends `B_impl`, but what should `E_impl` extends? `E_impl` implements both `C` and `D` but I can't extend both `C_impl` and `D_impl` in Java. So what should I do?

Comment: There is no multiple inheritance in Java. However, you can implement multiple interfaces.

Comment: B cant extend C and D, as there are now multiple inheritance in java, but B can extend C and be wrapper around class D

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 solutions:

1. Have D extend C (or vice versa).  That way when E extends D it is also extending C.

   - Your hesitance would then look like A <- B <- C <- D <- E
2. Use interfaces instead of sub classes.

Hopefully 1 works without making too many complications.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do multiple inheritance in Java, but you can use multiple interfaces. Another cool solution is to rather than inherit, use lomboks @Delegate for one or both of the classes you want to extend, it will give you a lot of the same functionality in a cool, neat way.

http://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html

Answer (score 0):

what I see (If I understood the Q right), your problem is on `E/E_impl` so what you want to do (impl omitted):

```
 A <-  B <- C <---+         
       ^           \        
       |            - E     
       +----D <---+/
```

**solution 1**  (skip the `E` interface).

```
              (implements)  
 A <-  B <- C <|--+         
       ^           \        
       |            - E_impl (normal class)
       +----D <|--+/        
              (implements)
```

In this way, your object of type `E_impl` **is a** `C` and `D` (of course AB too) If you really want to have a general/abstract type `E`, see solution 2

**solution 2**  (use an abstract class `EA` and your `E_impl` extends it)

```
               (implements)
 A <-  B <- C <|--+
       ^           \ 
       |            - EA(abstract class) <--(extends)--E_impl
       +----D <|--+/
              (implements)
```

In this case, your `E_impl` **is a** `EA, C, D, B, A`

I hope this answers your question.

Also consider if ***composition*** could solve your problem.